# How to convert a curl command to fetch()?

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch-api

Here is my command:

```bash
curl -H 'API-Key: EXAMPLE' https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/label_set --data 'SUBID=576965' --data 'label=example'
```

I have tried

```js
fetch("https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/label_set", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "API-Key":"EXAMPLE"
    },
    data: "SUBID=576965&label=example",
})
```

and many others, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 11):

You could try this tool: https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/

Source on github: https://github.com/kigiri/fetch

Output:

```
fetch("https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/label_set", {
       body: "SUBID=576965&label=example",
       header: {
       "API-Key": "EXAMPLE",
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [curlconverter.com/javascript/](https://curlconverter.com/javascript/). It converts your command to

```js
fetch('https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/label_set', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'API-Key': 'EXAMPLE'
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        'SUBID': '576965',
        'label': 'example'
    })
});
```